# FlexboxLayout.getFlexLines() is 0 until after UI is updated

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to programmatically add views to a FlexboxLayout. When the layout has reached 3 wrapped lined, I want to stop adding things to the layout. The `maxLine` attribute wasn't useful as it starts to add too much on each horizontal line.

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:id="@+id/dynamic_button_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="584dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:alignContent="center"
    app:alignItems="center"
    app:flexDirection="row"
    app:flexWrap="wrap"
    app:justifyContent="center"/>
```

I initially tried the following in `onCreate`

```
        int viewNumber = 0;
        for (Button button : buttons){
            flexboxLayout.addView(button);

            if (flexboxLayout.getFlexLines().size() > 2){
                flexboxLayout.removeViewAt(viewNumber);
                break;
            }

            viewNumber++;
        }
```

The idea being if I've gone onto the 4th flex line, I just remove the last view and stop adding more views. The issue is that `.getFlexLines()` is always empty

If I do something like this, however, I the flex lines are returned correctly and I can start removing views. The problem with this is you can very briefly see the 4th line of buttons before they're removed.

```
        getWindow().getDecorView().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final FlexboxLayout flexboxLayout = findViewById(R.id.dynamic_button_layout);
                int lines = flexboxLayout.getFlexLines().size(); // this will be 4
            }
        });
```

Is there any way to get the number of flex lines before the UI is actually updated?

Comment: Instead of posting a runnable, try using the decor view's `ViewTreeObserver` and using `OnGlobalLayoutListener`. It's the same idea, but it might be early enough in the render cycle that you never see the 4th line.

Comment: @BenP. thanks a lot, Ben! That seems to have done the trick